# ios simulator and device first run code shows everytime

Tags: ios, uialertview, nsuserdefaults

My app has a welcome screen that shows the first time the app is run. I recently changed the text of the alert but notice the old alert screen shows for a second or two before the new version replaces it. It also appears on every launch of the app. It does this on my iPhone and the simulator. I erased the app from the phone. I erased it from the simulator and also reset the content and settings. I have cleaned the app. I tried clearing the simulator cache (derived data) with no luck. I tried renaming the nsuserdefaults key and the name of the alert. The old alert still shows on app launch and is also not clickable. I have to wait for it to disappear.

First run code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"onetime"] boolValue]) {
    NSLog(@"first run");   //This only shows the first time so I know code is okay below
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"onetime"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    UIAlertView *onetime = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:@" -message here-" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [onetime show];
  }
}
```

I know the code itself is okay because of the log. I don't understand why an old alert is showing or how to get rid of it. I am sure it won't happen on new installs but I would like to make sure.

**EDIT:**

The app has localization and I reloaded the files. Cleaned, Rebuild, Reset content and settings, and now the app starts clean the first time. Everytime after that it will show the new alert for 1 second and disappear. No log of first run. The alert image is being cached somehow.  Also, the alert is not part of the localization. No string files or plist. Just coded above in the viewdidload.  How is this showing up without being called in viewdidload?

**SOLVED**

I finally found the problem. The old screen that kept showing up is the launch image.  Sometimes it's the simple stuff. It was showing before viewdidload and that led me to check where it could come from.

Comment: Do you have another alertView somewhere else in your code?  Also, put a break point to stop the debugger at your [onetime show]; line and look at the stack trace to see where it is getting called from.

Comment: Your `if` statement should be: `if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"onetime"])`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I recently changed the wording"? you mean message?

Comment: I put a break point at the -(void)viewDidLoad and the old Alert shows up before the debugger stops. The old alert always shows. On first run it gets replaced by the new alert and on subsequent runs it shows and then disappears after 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

If log shows once then the problem is somewhere else. Try to clean project ( shift + command + K ) and try again.

Comment: Also try resetting the simulator with **iOS Simulator** → **Reset Content and Settings…**.